# How to get dynamic fields in tastypie per object

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have an api with fields a,b,c

I want to return fields a, b for all records.

But want to return field "c" only for current user.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve you need to write a [dehydrate](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html#dehydrate) for the Resource Class,
this is the example, you need to do the following.

```
class MyModelResource(Resource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = MyModel.objects.all()

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        # get logged-in user
        user = bundle.request.user

        # check whether it is the same logged-in user.
        if user.id == bundle.data['user_id']:
            # Remove the field 'c'
            del bundle.data['c']
        return bundle
```